# A hint to the differential equation $y^2(1-y'^2)=C$ for some real constant $C$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title suggests, I am seeking for some kind of hint to the above differential equation, just to get started. I've been sitting all afternoon without any kind of progress.

My approach so far has been substituting $y$ for some various trigonometric functions; however no luck.

Edit: I don't know how much of critical information this is, but $y(0)=0$ is to be satisfied.

Comment: Solve for $y'$ and you can turn this into a separable ODE

Comment: Well, I'd say $y(0)=0$ *is* sort of critical, because substituting $x=0$, you'll  find that $C=0$, and then, solving your equation is trivial.

Comment: @NoNames Well of course, how could I miss *that*. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @Cameron_Williams said try solving for $y'$

$$y^2(1-y'^2)=C$$

> $$1-y'^2=\dfrac{C}{y^2}$$

> $$y'^2=1-\dfrac{C}{y^2}$$

$$y'=\;\;?$$

Can you find it now?